# Can awk separate empty fields?

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to use awk to deal with a file in which each type of data has a fixed max length but actual length of data can be less than the max length and data even can be empty.

Let's simplify the problem,

```
echo 'a b   d e f' | awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="1 1 1 1 1 1" -v OFS=, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'
```

I have six fields in a line and their length is just 1, but the third field in this case is empty.
The expected output should be

> a,b, ,d,e,f

But what I got is

> a,b,d,e,f,

The empty third field is not correctly delimited.
Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: That output has absolutely no relationship with the purported code. And I have no idea what you mean when you say that the fieldwidth is fixed but can be less; either it is fixed or it is not fixed. (Perhaps you mean that there is a maximum fieldwidth?) Anyway, you cannot specify both that there is a delimiter and that there is no delimiter, as only one of those claims can be true. If you set `FIELDWIDTH`, then a previous assignment to `FS` is ignored, and vice versa.

Comment: I don't understand how you got that splitting with `FS="FS"`. You've literally asked for the characters `FS` to be the field separator. These do not appear in your data, so it should be treated as one field.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results using any version of awk available to me.  I come closest when using mawk (Mike's awk -- are you on Ubuntu?).  Mawk ignores `FIELDWIDTHS`.

Comment: @RobinWang : Is each field(even empty) in the input delimited by a space for sure?

Comment: @John1024 `FIELDWIDTH` seems to be something GNU `sed` has.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, that is correct: _GNU_ awk supports FIELDWIDTHS.  (I presume that you meant to type awk).

Comment: With GNU `awk` (which supports FIELDWIDTHS), you can get the required result with: `echo 'a b   d e f' | awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1" -v OFS=, '{print $1,$3,$5,$7,$9,$11}'`, but better alternatives are available for this splitting.

Comment: @John1024 Yes, I meant awk, not sed. Too many sed questions lately...

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can't rely on the built-in field splitting which relies on delimiters.  Instead, you need to convert your FIELDWIDTHS to column positions and widths `(1,1) (3,1) (5,1) (7,1) (9,1) (11, 1)` and then use `substr` to extract the data:

```
$ echo 'a b   d e f' | awk '{print substr($0, 3, 1)}'
b
$ echo 'a b   d e f' | awk '{print substr($0, 5, 1)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This reproduces your results:

```
$ echo 'a b   d e f' | mawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="1 1 1 1 1 1" -v OFS=, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'
a,b,d,e,f,
```

As for why it is not working as you expect, note that you get the same results *without* FIELDWIDTHS:

```
$ echo 'a b   d e f' | mawk -v OFS=, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'
a,b,d,e,f,
```

This is because mawk (Mike's awk) ignores FIELDWIDTHS.  If you want FIELDWIDTHS, you have to use GNU awk.  But, note that setting the field width to 1 does not do what you want:

```
$ echo 'a b   d e f' | gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="1 1 1 1 1 1" -v OFS=, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'
a, ,b, , ,
```

This is because, when using FIELDWIDTHS, GNU awk assumes that **no** field separators are present.  If you really want to do it this way and keep your desired field numbering, you need to set the field widths to 2:

```
$ echo 'a b   d e f' | gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="2 2 2 2 2 2" -v OFS=, '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'
a ,b ,  ,d ,e ,f
```

Aside from the extra space that tags along, this is what you wanted.

Alternatively, as anishsane suggested in the comments, you can use single-character field widths if you are willing to change the field numbering.  Using only odd numbered fields in the output:

```
$ echo 'a b   d e f' | awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1" -v OFS=, '{print $1,$3,$5,$7,$9,$11}'
a,b, ,d,e,f
```

This works and eliminates the unwanted spaces.